# Express cache middleware typescript definition

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I have an express middleware function that caches the response. This is my inspiration [Medium post](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/simple-server-side-cache-for-express-js-with-node-js-45ff296ca0f0). I am having trouble creating it in typescript. I can't figure out which types are needed to change the send function.

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import NodeCache from 'node-cache'
const myCache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 60 * 5 })

const cache = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const key = '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url
  const cachedBody: string | undefined = myCache.get(key)
  if (cachedBody) {
    return res.send(cachedBody)
  } else {
    const sendResponse = res.send
    // error: Type '(body: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'Send<any, Response<any, Record<string, any>>>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.
    res.send = (body) => {
      myCache.set(key, JSON.stringify(body))
      sendResponse(body)
    }
    next()
  }
}
```

I was able to use the function in a vanilla js project. But it would be great if someone could indicate what the correct types are or maybe have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the value (anonymous function) assigned to `res.send` must fully implement the interface of real `res.send()`. You can just forward the value you get from the original `res.send()` which is the output of `sendResponse`;

To fix it just change

```
res.send = (body) => {
  myCache.set(key, JSON.stringify(body))
  sendResponse(body)
}
```

to

```
res.send = (body) => {
  myCache.set(key, JSON.stringify(body))
  return sendResponse(body) // <---- Here you must return something
}
```